# Debug application closing

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, jenkins

I have a .NET 3.5 console app running in parallel (4-6 instances).

On my development machine + other Win7 machines everything works fine.
   On a Jenkins server all instances start and shut down after approx 1 min at the same time with no logging information + any obvious reason.

I am also using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` so it seems there is no Unhandled exception.
  My question is how can I debug what is stopping my apps if it is not crashing?
  The `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` event is being called, is there any information in the sender object that I can use, maybe last routine that executed?

Comment: Are there any timeouts configured on the Jenkins server that would result in your process being terminated if it ran for longer than 60 seconds? (you didn't specify how the processes were being launched, but if the jobs have a timeout configured it may be responsible). Short of that, the NT Event logs *may* have some additional information about the process termination.

Comment: Hello, timeout on the Jenkins server is set to 24 hours. In the Event Viewer there is nothing logged.

Comment: You may try procdump -t <pid> or procdump -t -x <dmp-file> <your-exe-file> <args> - it will create a dump when your process terminates. You may download procdump from live.sysinternals.com

Comment: I am currently waiting on a machine with the same configuration as the production Jenkins server. I will then try procdump to see what is stoping the processes. Thanks for the hint.